# anylogic triggering an event

Tags: anylogic

In accordance, I have a question in the modeling process. I want my agent to have an event that is triggered by time and condition, example: goToSchool if it is more than 6 am and there is a school bus. I am confused about whether to use the timeout trigger (but cannot use the condition) or the condition (but cannot use the timeout) or is there any possible alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "if it is more than 6 am" is a condition and not a timeout. A timeout trigger is used when you want an event to happen at an exact time. In your case, while "more than 6 am" is time related, it is still a condition. So I would use a condition triggered event with two conditions:

```
getHourOfDay() > 6 && <bus condition>
```

getHourOfDay() function returns the hour of the day in a 24-hr format.

You need to keep in mind something important related to condition triggered events, they are only evaluated "on change". I recommend you read this carefully:

https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fstatecharts%2Fcondition-event.html

My recommendation would be to use the `onChange()` function in the block controlling your bus arrival so that the condition is evaluated each time a bus arrives.

Comment: It helps a lot! Surely, I'll read it thoroughly and carefully for future development. Thank you in advance!